Create random polyhedral aggregates
I'm seeking guidance on utilizing Geometry Nodes to create random convex polyhedral aggregates with varying sizes in cube, ensuring they do not intersect, as depicted in the attached image. Could you provide instructions on achieving this effect? Thank you!.

